# How to Express Panic Buying in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I was going to mention panic-buying in Joonas's apposite Q:[What should the corona virus be called in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/13379/1982); but as answers poured in, it seemed less & less appropriate.

Running concomitant with (the fear of) the Coronavirus, the regrettable phenomenon of panic-buying. To express this, in Latin, the well-known phrase "delirium tremens" = "frenzied shaking", the violent, physiological reaction to alcohol withdrawal, could be adapted, giving: "delirium emens" = "frenzied/ crazed buying".

Alternatively, the nominative of the gerund, the infinitive: "timere est emere" = "fearing is buying".

Supermarkets claim to disapprove of panic-buying; but, is this really credible? For them it may be a case of (borrowing Tom-Cotton's astute technique on Q:[A Convenient Co-operation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11127/1982), of adapting Caligula's infamous, pithy aphorism):

"metuant dum emant" = "let them fear, provided that they buy".

Any thoughts on a translation of "panic-buying"?

Comment: Germans say _cricetare_ ;-) – https://www.dw.com/en/a-52635400

Answer (score 2):

A rather literal translation would be **emptio ex pavore**. If you can live with a word that strictly only refers to food, you could also say **frumentatio ex pavore**. *Frumentatio* seems to be more of a military word, but I say it fits in this case. I think you could also use the plural and say **emptiones**, but *frumentationes*, perhaps not so much. (My dictionary says that would be the baggage train.)

Stressing less the motive (panic) and more the excessiveness of the behaviour, you could also say **emptiones nimiae** or **immoderatae**, or perhaps **Nimium emendi**.

Note that “panic buying” is a rather specific and also somewhat judgemental term, implying the purchases are irrational and likely useless. Depending on the circumstances, such buying patterns may also be sensible. A more neutral term could therefore be something like **copias coacervare** (or *coacervatio copiarum*?), or perhaps *accumulare*.

Comment: Sebastian Koppehel: Thank you. The British press has made light of panic-buying--it's all a bit of a joke--empty shelves reminiscent of a scene from the Third World. These things can turn ugly; food riots, savagery. We think that we are immune from such circumstances--is that true? It was the potential nightmares that I attempted to encapsulate in "delirium emens".