# World War One: Opening Moves

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

On [Q "We Are Triumphant While Our enemy Sleeps"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11065/79) the comment was made: "Remember the Schlieffen Plan? Brilliant; inspired gamble; but, it could have only have worked if the belligerent nations had conveniently co-operated--they didn't."

A possible translation could be:

> "consilium imperatoris mortui reminisceris? ingeniosum; ludo incenso deis belli, si hostes-patriae adiuvissent, id confecisset."

(How to say "inspired gamble"?!?)

Is this correct?

Continuing on the same theme: with war having been declared and the (ambitious) Schlieffen Plan about to be implemented, German Chancellor, Bethmann-Holweg, advised Europe: "We must hack our way through!"

A (succinct) translation could be:

> "secabimus!" = "We will hack our way through!"

This, of course, is not quite the same thing. It lacks obligation "must". Therefore, invoking instruction from Q: [Nunc est bibendum: gerund or gerundive?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10809/1982) = "Now one must drink", to give:

> "nunc est secandum!" = "Now one must hack-a-way-through!"

I'm not sure about this, is it open to improvement?

An alternative: "perrumpemus" (from perrumpo) = "We will break/ force our way through!"; "We will overcome!"

"nunc est perrumpendum!" = "Now one must break through!"

Comment: Joonas llmavirta: Apologies: did try to link the old Qs., but it just said "Link-copied-to-clipboard"??

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Finally sorted the linking technique--yippee! Did yourself watch the press conference with your President & Trump? Any thoughts?

Comment: I sent you an invitation to [our site's chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) recently. Many small tech support things and especially discussions not related to the questions and answers work best there. Chat also allows having more structured conversations, as the main site is not really built for discussions at all. Have you tried chat? You can drop in and say hi at any time, even if nobody is in at the moment.